# Rewrite rule for .htaccess delete "/"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have problems with the url pointing to my site type:
http://www.domain.com/document.php/
If you see an " *.php/ " or " *.html/ " at the end of the route, the document does not charge styles, javascripts and functions is displayed php evil. I wish through the .htaccess create a rule that if the route is in the end a " *.php/ " or " *.html/ " delete the "/" to work properly. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in `.htacess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php/$ $1.php
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html/$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

before trying `.htacess`
please be sure to change `apache2.conf`

find and replace `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` for the `<Directory>` directive pointing to your public web pages where the htaccess file resides

if you are using ubuntu you can find `apache2.conf` under the path `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

here `/var/www/` is the path where your `.htacess` resides

EDIT : 
A better way as suggested by @hjpotter in comments

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(php|html)/$ $1.$2
</IfModule>
```

Comment: A single `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(php|html)/$ $1.$2` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you sir :) I too am a beginner, Edited answer as you suggested :)

Comment: you are welcome :) if it worked for you, 
please mark it as Answer